# Issues Setting Up Istio Gateway

Tags: istio

I have an AKS cluster with 2 nodes

Node A. 10.216.6.229 Node B. 10.216.6.230

We do not have External Load Balancer, so Istio Gateway EXTERNAL-IP is . As per Get Started documentation, I used command below to get INGRESS-HOST, which was set to Node A IP of 10.216.6.229. After completing the Get Started steps I can open sample app BookInfo on http://10.216.6.229:30438/productpage

```
export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl get po -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.items[0].status.hostIP}')
```

Here’s the questions I have

1. For some reason http://10.216.6.230:30438/productpage is also responding. I don’t understand how the traffic is routed to Node B address.
2. What happens if Node A with IP 10.216.6.229 crashes and is restarted with a different IP address?
3. Is Node Port a proper configuration for production environment?
4. Can I install Istio with EXTERNAL-IP configured? I was able to do this with NGinx.

Thanks for the information.

**EDIT 1**

I am still struggling with this. I have tried to install Istio with loadBalancerIP, and I get error message below

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: demo
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            loadBalancerIP: 10.215.5.254
```

Event message:
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: findMatchedPIPByLoadBalancerIP: cannot find public IP with IP address 10.215.5.254 in resource group rg_mc_kub11618np01

My subnet is 10.215.5.224/27

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to create a Public IP Address which should depend on the AKS cluster.

I have used Pulumi as IaC tool for creating public IP Address and added the option `dependsOn` with the cluster information.

Initialize the istio operator as follows:

```
istioctl operator init
```

And then, you use the public Address `ipAddress` inside this like the following:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istiocontrolplane
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  profile: demo
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            loadBalancerIP: <publicIPAddress.ipAddress>
```

Or you can directly call like the following:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            loadBalancerIP: <publicIPAddress.ipAddress>
EOF
```

This way istio is associated with your AKS cluster and follow the steps accordingly. I hope this helps :)